# Como adaptar o Hibernate ao padrão DAO?

Tags: java, hibernate, padrão-dao

Estou começando a estudar `Hibernate` e queria "começar da forma certa".
A duvida é a seguinte:

Para toda a transação eu preciso utilizar o seguinte código:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
```

e para salvar

```
    Empregado emp = new Empregado();
    emp.setEmail("teste@mail.com");
    emp.setNome("Jose");
    emp.setSobenome("Alves");

    session.save(emp);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Já estou habituado com o padrão `DAO` mas utilizando `JDBC`.
Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de se utilizar as `Sessions` junto com o padrão `DAO`.
Se, por exemplo, eu teria que abrir a `Session` e fechar em todos os métodos do `DAO`, ou se teria algum outro jeito para não alocar recursos desnecessários.
Se puderem colar um exemplo eu agradeceria.

Comment: Qual é a dúvida exatamente? Para uma classe no model, você cria uma correspondente no dao? Se sim, eu não vejo problema nisso. Por exemplo: suponha que você tenha uma classe Empregado.java dentro de model, com suas características. Lá no dao, suponha que você tenha EmpregadoDAO.java com o método `save()`. Neste método, você vai colocar esse código que você mostrou na pergunta. Toda vez que você precisar salvar um empregado, é só chamar o método `save()` para esse empregado. É isso que você faz?

Comment: Seria mais ou menos isso. A minha duvida mesmo é se em todos os métodos do `DAO`eu teria que ficar abrindo a `Session` e a `Transaction` repetidamente ou se teria alguma melhor forma de fazer isso.

Comment: Entendi. Eu uso desse jeito, tendo visto alguns códigos pela net. Mas não sei se é o melhor jeito.

Comment: Tem que abrir e fechar a session sempre, e tem que iniciar e fechar a transação sempre. Mas não faz muito sentido fazer isso em cada método do DAO pois você pode querer utilizar mais de um método em uma mesma transação. Geralmente obtem-se a session e inicializa-se a transação no começo de cada serviço do aplicativo, e você pode usar frameworks para poupar serviço. A melhor maneira de fazer, entretanto, depende de mais informações sobre o seu sistema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Padrão DAO nada mais é que isolar todo acesso a banco de dados em uma única camada. No java utilizamo os pacotes para isolar o acesso.

JDBC nada mais é que a API disponibilizada pelo JAVA que lhe permite acesso aos bancos de dados, mas isso fica a depender da implementação que você irá utilizar, no caso o drive que você vai adicionar ao seu projeto.

**update**

Segue um exemplo bem básico de um sistema em camadas Modelo, DAO e Service. Nele é possivel ver que cada classe executa apenas uma atividade.
Para um exemplo mais completo fica faltando apenas a camada VIEW de apresentação das informações.

```
public class Pessoa{

    private Int id;
    private String nome;
    private Int idade;
    //...outro metodos
}

public class PessoaDao{

    public Boolean salvar(Pessoa pessoa){

        Boolean resultado = false;
        try{
            Connection con = Factory.getConnection();
            String insertComand = "insert into tb_pessoa values(?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement cmd=con.preparedStatement(insertComand);
            cmd.setInt(1,pessoa.getId());
            cmd.setString(2,pessoa.getNome());
            cmd.setInt(3,pessoa.getIdade());
            cmd.execute();
            resultado=true;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            resultado=false;
        }

        return resultado;
    }

}

public class PessoaService{

    private PessoaDao pessoaDao;

    public boolean salvarPessoa(Pessoa pessoa){
        pessoaDao = new PessoaDao();
        return pessoaDao.salvar(pessoa);
    }
}
```

Comment: A resposta é boa, mas seria melhor se tivesse um exemplo que não dependesse de um link externo. :)

Comment: Também concordo com o que o @utluiz disse. Além disso, o link não está mais funcionando (404).

Comment: JDBC não é o drive em si, é uma API que provem formas de interação com a base de dados. Ele não funciona se não houver o driver do SGBD adicionado.